# htaccess redirect static to dynamic by extracting an ID from the URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL like

railroad-worker-decal-p-18196.html

I need to redirect it to

index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=18196

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the id and use it in the rewrite:

RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(\d+).html$ index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$2